# Vim: list most recent buffers for a given pane

Tags: vim

In most text editors with tabs and panes, I tend to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between tabs in a given pane. Vim's `bp` quickly switches to the previous file in the buffer list, but **is there a way to switch to the last open file in a given pane?**

It would be even more ideal if it allows you to quickly cycle, such as what <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does for windows in Linux and Windows (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for OS X).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are asking but I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> to switch back to the last buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`gt` and `gT` allow you to cycle the tabs forward and backward, respectively.